# How to set range of year in x axis in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I am new to d3js and i am having a problem with mi d3 line chart, well if you can see my chart is showing all the data by year, but my problem is that what i want to do and i dont know how, is it to appear year by year in the x axis but it is showing like this.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc2Vf.png)

It is for every 5 year and i want it to appear year by year.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhjsA.png)

This is a part of my code:

```
 //Set the ranges for the line
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

//Define the 1st line
var valueline = d3.line()

.x(function(d) { return x(d.DATE); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.DDDM01USA156NWDB); });


//Set the domains for the lines
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.DATE; }));

y.domain([20, 160]);

//Set axis for the lines
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y);

//Gridlines in x axis function
var gridlineX = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickFormat("");


//Add the X gridlines
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(gridlineX);

//Gridlines in y axis function
var gridlineY = d3.axisLeft()
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat("%")
    .scale(y);

//Add the Y gridlines
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid2")
    .call(gridlineY);

//--------------Add the valueline path------------------
//Path (line Chart) transitions
function lineTransition(path) {
    path.transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash);
}

function tweenDash() {
    var l = this.getTotalLength(),
        i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);

    return function(t) {
        return i(t);
    };
}

//Add the valueline path for line 1
svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("id", "line1")
    .style("stroke", "#7C6CAA")
    .style("stroke-width", "3")
    .attr("d", valueline);
//Transition
svg.select("#line1")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", valueline)
    .call(lineTransition);

//xlabel    
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," +
        (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".80em")
    .text("Year");
//ylabel
svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .text("Percent");

//Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis axisGrey")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

//Add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis axisGrey")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .style("font-size", "12px")
```

And my csv file where i get the data is this:

DATE,DDDM01USA156NWDB,year,Dato
1/1/1984,42.5146,1984,0
1/1/1985,44.873,1985,0
1/1/1986,52.5561,1986,0
1/1/1987,52.3852,1987,0
1/1/1988,50.667,1988,0
1/1/1989,54.6595,1989,0
1/1/1990,54.5632,1990,160
1/1/1991,58.7687,1991,160
1/1/1992,66.732,1992,0
1/1/1993,71.4563,1993,0
1/1/1994,71.3222,1994,0
1/1/1995,79.144,1995,0
1/1/1996,95.619,1996,0
1/1/1997,112.103,1997,0
1/1/1998,130.576,1998,0
1/1/1999,143.673,1999,0
1/1/2000,146.193,2000,0
1/1/2001,138.332,2001,160
1/1/2002,114.902,2002,0
1/1/2003,110.685,2003,0
1/1/2004,125.554,2004,0
1/1/2005,128.392,2005,0
1/1/2006,133.386,2006,0
1/1/2007,137.361,2007,160
1/1/2008,109.698,2008,160
1/1/2009,92.9573,2009,160
1/1/2010,108.321,2010,0
1/1/2011,107.384,2011,0
1/1/2012,107.025,2012,0
1/1/2013,128.708,2013,0
1/1/2014,146.209,2014,0
1/1/2015,142.648,2015,0
1/1/2016,141.286,2016,0
1/1/2017,153.96,2017,0

Comment: Hey @DeathInWhite, please add your code and attempt to create your range so we can help you with fixing it.

Comment: There it is, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [axis.ticks()](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks) method to specify the number of ticks you would like for an axis.

This doesn't guarantee that `d3` will render your requested number of ticks. Rather, `d3` will try to choose a number of ticks close to your request that still makes sense for your data.

In other words, it won't show intervals that aren't intuitive for a human to understand, like 1.2387 of a year, and will instead show something more sensible like a half-year, a year etc.

But, I think if you know the min and max values of your time domain, then you will be able to provide the number of years in that domain as an argument to the `ticks()` method.

```
var minYear = d3.min(data, d => d.date).getFullYear();
var maxYear = d3.max(data, d => d.date).getFullYear();
var numYears = maxYear - minYear;
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(numYears);
```

Comment: OMG! It worked, thanks! I owe you my life, you are amazing!